# How to run SQL script in JDBC without iBatis?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have this code with iBatis :

```
  try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(connection);
        sr.setAutoCommit(true);
        Reader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("start.sql"));
        Reader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("create.sql"));

        sr.runScript(reader1);
        sr.runScript(reader2);
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null) connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And It works but I need to run this script without using iBatis.

Any ideas?

Comment: It depends a bit on the driver. Some drivers do allow running multiple statements with a single `execute()` call (even though this should not be the case according to the JDBC specification).

Answer (score 1):

1. read .sql file as String
2. split every single sql into ArrayList,and then iterate
3. Use Statement to execute batched sql under sql transaction
4. access the SQL with args rewriteBatchedStatements=true，the you can execute batched sql

would be like:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false); // start Tx
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
for(String sql : sqlStrings){
  statement.addBatch(sql);       // batched sql
}
statement.executeBatch()
connection.commit()
```

Comment: You don't need to use a prepared statement for this. Using a (single) `java.sql.Statement` should be sufficient. In addition, you are leaking your statements right now: always create statements in a try-with-resources block to ensure they are closed.

Comment: its sure to use try-catch block but omited in my codes，I assume this is a basic knowledge.
and its right to use Statement instead of PreparedStatmen,cause PreparedStatement will compiled and batch for different parameters but not support different sql

Comment: A try-with-resources is something different than try-catch (example: `try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) { ... }`). Also, `Statement` has no `commit()` method.

Comment: thanks again,wrong typing with commit().
i'll figure it out what try-with-resources do.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to read `.sql` file as `String` and then split it by delimiter `;` and execute sequentially.

Comment: Can u write your code plz?
I tried to do it by myself but I can't

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use third party libs, try mine:
Add maven dependency:
   `<dependency> 
        <groupId>com.github.buckelieg</groupId> 
        <artifactId>db-fn</artifactId> <version>0.3.4</version> 
    </dependency>`

And use the code:
     `db.script(new File("path/to/script.sql")).timeout(60).execute();`

See more [here](https://github.com/buckelieg/db-fn/blob/master/README.md#scripts)